# How can I move a child object to a target position using python?

Tags: python

I want to be able to move the child object to any known position.

Find below an example:
[image]

The "Child" object must be in this exact position (-2,3,4) with no offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the location of an object to a target position specified in world space simply set the translation value of the object's world matrix

```
child_obj.matrix_world.translation = target
```

Comment: Should be : child.matrix_world.translation = target.location or child.matrix_world.translation = target.matrix_world.translation  right ?

Comment: target is a tuple or [mathutils.Vector](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils.vector#mathutils.Vector) of dimension 3. So both assignments would work. Though `.location` attribute of an object might differ from its world space location.

Answer (score 0):

```
bpy.context.scene.objects["Child"].matrix_local = bpy.context.scene.objects["New Loc"].matrix_world
```

Is that what you're looking for ?

EDIT : this will affect to your child object the same matrix as the target, including rotation/scale...

Comment: Hi Flavio ,
I've a (x,y,z) world coordinate to place the child object.
I need the "Child" object to be in this exact position (x,y,z) with no offset.

Comment: I was close :) It didn't realise until pink vertex answer i could take just the translation of a matrix_world of an object :)